# how to repeat a loop in matlab

Tags: matlab

The given `for loop` calculates a new transition matrix. I am trying for a

I want to repeat the given loop,smartly, but its dubious to copy/paste the loop again and again. please help.

```
 %% generate some weights vector i.e. the probability matrix
 Transition = 
[              
               0.06    0.47   0      0.47   0      0      0;
               0.47    0.06   0.47   0      0      0      0;
               0       0.47   0.06   0.47   0      0      0;
               0.47    0      0.47   0.037  0.023  0      0;
               0       0      0      0.023  0.037  0.47   0.47;
               0       0      0      0      0.47   0.06   0.47;
               0       0      0      0      0.47   0.47   0.06
];

tolerance= 0.01

Dij= Transition;
len=length(Transition);
enter code here

%% copying the status
for i=1:7 

    while(1)
        sel=randi(7);
        if((Dij(i,sel) ~= 0))
            show(i)=sel;
            break;
        end
    end

    Dij(i,sel)=Dij(i,sel)-tolerance*(i ~= sel);
    for i=1:7
     while(1)
        sel=randi(7);
        if((NewDij(i,sel) ~= 0))
            show(i)=sel;
            break;
        end
    end

    NewDij(i,sel)=NewDij(i,sel)-tolerance*(i ~= sel);
    newnew=NewDij;
end

 for i=1:7
     while(1)
        sel=randi(7);
        if((newnew(i,sel) ~= 0))
            show(i)=sel;
            break;
        end
    end

    newnew(i,sel)=NewDij(i,sel)-tolerance*(i ~= sel);

end
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: why not just put another loop around the sections you're copy/pasting? Also what exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: Repeat the loop to achieve what? Are you trying to update your transition matrix? Also, pasting code won't help. Tell us what you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, do you have any termination condition: when to stop updating Dij.

You can add the Dij updating within the loop itself by defining it under the `if` condition.

So instead of

```
if((Dij(i,sel) ~= 0))
    show(i)=sel;
    break;
```

you can write

```
if((Dij(i,sel) ~= 0))
    show(i)=sel;
    Dij(i,sel)=Dij(i,sel)-tolerance*(i ~= sel);
```

Answer (score 1):

I see that you have a code snippet that occurs twice in the code.
Assuming this is what you mean by repeating, you can define a function or script that contains this code, and then call this twice rather than copypasting the code. This way there is also not the risk of updating the code in one location but not in the second.

When there are limited input and output arguments a function is typically preferred, check `help function`

---

As a sidenote, I don't know whether a `while 1 ... break` is really bad practice but I think it is at least unusual.